# How to add emojis section

Tags: flutter, icons

I am building a chat app and was trying to add a button that opens like a keyboard with all the emojis. Same as what whatsapp does. I know that those are their emojis but is there some package that does the same functionality.

I tried searching pub.dev but found none. Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: try this package [emoji_picker_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/emoji_picker_flutter)